# Programmatically access format-suppression formulas

Tags: formatting, crystal-reports, formula, reportdocument

I want to programmatically scan the suppression formulas of a text object in a Crystal report using the `ReportDocument` object. The reports were designed using version XI R2 (11.5)

I am able to iterate through the various objects within ReportDocument but I can't seem to programmatically view the formula within a text object using either `ReportDefinition` or `DataDefinition`. Standalone formulas do show up in DataDefinition.FormulaFields, but I am trying to view formulas that are embedded in a text object (such as a suppression formula).  How can I do this, or is this a known limitation of the ReportDocument object?

Comment: Have you considered abstracting out the formulas into Formula objects and having the format formulas reference the objects?

Comment: Too much work for me.  Why, is there no way to scan the embedded formulas?

Comment: In all my time working with Crystal I've never encountered a way to scan embedded formulas. But if you copy the logic to an external Formula Object, you'll have a much easier time modifying or comparing them. Especially if some of them overlap and you're able to satisfy multiple objects with a single formula.

Comment: What is your goal ? Are you trying to compare the formulas or to modify them ?

Comment: I'm trying to scan all the database fields that are used within crystal for all my reports (500+) and keep them at hand so that if changes are made to the database schema (rename or delete columns) I will know which reports to modify/update without having to open and verify all of them manually.